# Spring Test Junit throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, testing, junit, spring-test

I have this code for testing :

```
private static final Integer documentSetId = 1143;
private static final Integer dsLifeCycleStateId = 1;
private static final String dsLifecycleState = "CVS_CREATED";

CVBusiness cvBusinessTest;


DocumentService documentService;

DocumentSetRepository documentSetRepository;

private DocumentSet documentSet;

private DSLifeCycleState dsLifeCycleState;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    cvBusinessTest = new CVBusinessImpl();
    documentService = mock(DocumentService.class);  
    documentSetRepository = mock(DocumentSetRepository.class);

    documentSet = new DocumentSet();
    dsLifeCycleState = new DSLifeCycleState();

    documentSet.setActive(true);
    documentSet.setDocumentSetId(documentSetId);
    documentSet.setMarkedForTranslation(false);

    dsLifeCycleState.setDsLifeCycleStateId(dsLifeCycleStateId);
    dsLifeCycleState.setLabel(dsLifecycleState);

    documentSet.setDsLifeCycleState(dsLifeCycleState);

    when(documentService.getDocumentSetById(documentSetId)).thenReturn(documentSet);
    when(documentService.updateDocumentSet(documentSet)).thenReturn(documentSet);
    when(documentSetRepository.findOne(documentSetId)).thenReturn(documentSet);
}

@Test
public void markedForTranslationTest() {

    boolean retValue = true;

    DocumentSet docSet = documentService.getDocumentSetById(documentSetId);
    dsLifeCycleState = docSet.getDsLifeCycleState();

    if (dsLifeCycleState.getLabel().equals(LifeCycleStateEnum.CVS_CREATED.message()) && docSet.isActive() && !docSet.isMarkedForTranslation() && ((docSet.getfDR() == null) || docSet.getfDR().equals(""))){
        documentSet.setMarkedForTranslation(true);
        retValue = documentService.updateDocumentSet(documentSet) != null;
    }

   // retValue = cvBusinessTest.markedForTranslation(documentSetId);

    assertTrue(retValue); 

}
```

and when i run Junit, it finished with errors:
java.lang null pointer exception.

Which error points the method bellow

DocumentSet documentSet = documentService.getDocumentSetById(id)

which is in CVBusiness package extended by CVBusinessImpl.

My question is why documentService in CVBusinessImpl throws Null exception?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: Where does the exception occur, which line?

Comment: Exception occurs when I uncomment this line : 
retValue = cvBusinessTest.markedForTranslation(documentSetId);
and refers on CVBusiness.java line 100 which contains this method i have post above                                           (DocumentSet documentSet = documentService.getDocumentSetById(id))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you missed to use Spring in your Test? How the `documentService` is injected?

Add `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to your test class to enable Spring in the test. If you use autowire that should be all. You may also need a `@ContextConfiguration` annotation to your test and/or add `@Resource` to the members to be injected.

Comment: Yes i have include @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class), but i think the problem is the documentService injection. I don't include any context configuration xml. Should i have to create a mock instance of documentService into the context conf xml? Because I thought that i had already did in my code as it is above

Comment: How your injection is happening in production? Autowired, property setter? XML or annotation based? Use a similar setup in your test (a small xml file, some @Resource annotations in your test, ...)

Answer (score 0):

In your setup, you create your class to test:

```
cvBusinessTest = new CVBusinessImpl();
```

and one of the services it requires:

```
documentService = mock(DocumentService.class);
```

but you never wire them together. So when your `CVBusinessImpl` implementation calls:

```
DocumentSet documentSet = documentService.getDocumentSetById(id)
```

`documentService` is still `null`.

You should wire your objects before testing, either through using a Spring test runner or through setting that field. Something in your setup method like:

```
cvBusinessTest.setDocumentService(documentService);
```